# Android Database Access Across Tabs

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have four tabs (reports, review reports, map and settings). I have an sqlite database populated with report information. I wish to have the database accessible throughout the application. The reports tab successfully adds data to the database however using the same methodology crashes the application. The Android debugger points to the line where the database is called again.

In the reports tab the following code is used to launch the database...

```
this.reportDatabase = new ReportDatabase(this);
  this.reportDatabase.insert("(" + latitude + ", " + longitude + ", " + time + ", '" + spinnerState + "', " + lower + ", " + upper + ", " + agreed + ", " + getAlgorithmCount() + ", " + xAxis + ", " + yAxis + ", " + zAxis + ", " + altitude + ", "+ accuracy + ", 'photo');");
```

In the onCreate() method of the Review Tab - Where I wish to review reports - I try to access to the database through the call calling the return report method

this.reportDatabase = new ReportDatabase(this);

However this fails to work. In the android debugger highlights that the problem belongs with the context being provided to it. I realise that the report database has already been accessed by the report tab and wonder if this is causing the issue. I am new to programming android, the application is designed to report on flamingos in Africa, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Following the suggestion of Seva Alekseyev I have adapted as follows...

I have adapted my ReportDatabase as...

```
 public ReportDatabase(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  ReportDatabase.context = context;
  OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(ReportDatabase.context);
  this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 }

 static ReportDatabase open(Context c){
  if(reportDatabase == null){
   reportDatabase = new ReportDatabase(ReportDatabase.context);
   return reportDatabase;
  }
  return reportDatabase;
 }
```

using...

```
 reportDatabase = ReportDatabase.open(this);
```

As the call in both the report and review tab. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, the debugger stops on the same method. The full ReportDatabase.java file is here...

```
package com.android.flamingo;

import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReportDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

static ReportDatabase reportDatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "flamingo_reports";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "reports";

/**
 * Default (and only) constructor....
 * 
 * @param context
 */

public ReportDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    ReportDatabase.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(ReportDatabase.context);
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

static ReportDatabase open(Context c){
    if(reportDatabase == null){
        reportDatabase = new ReportDatabase(ReportDatabase.context);
        return reportDatabase;
    }
    return reportDatabase;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param name
 */

public void insert(String name){
    this.database.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "(latitude, longitude, time, lake, lower_estimate, higher_estimate, agreed_estimate, algorithm_count, xaxis, yaxis, zaxis, altitude, accuracy, photo_identifier) VALUES " + name);
}

/**
 * This method returns a double array and probably shouldn't be this hacky...
 * 
 * 
 * @return
 */

public Vector<ReportInstanceQuery> reportSelect(){
    Vector<ReportInstanceQuery> tempReports = new Vector<ReportInstanceQuery>();

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT id,time,lake,lower_estimate,higher_estimate,agreed_estimate,algorithm_count FROM" + TABLE_NAME + ";",null);
    int indexTime = c.getColumnIndex("time");
    int indexLake = c.getColumnIndex("lake");
    int indexLowerEstimate = c.getColumnIndex("lower_estimate");
    int indexHigherEstimate = c.getColumnIndex("higher_estimate");
    int indexAgreedEstimate = c.getColumnIndex("agreed_estimate");
    int indexAlgorithmCount = c.getColumnIndex("algorithm_count");


    if (c != null){
        int i = 0;
        do {
            i++;
            int columnTime = c.getInt(indexTime);
            String columnLake = c.getString(indexLake);
            int columnLowerEstimate = c.getInt(indexLowerEstimate);
            int columnHigherEstimate = c.getInt(indexHigherEstimate);
            int columnAgreedEstimate = c.getInt(indexAgreedEstimate);
            int columnAlgorithmCount = c.getInt(indexAlgorithmCount);

            tempReports.add(new ReportInstanceQuery(columnTime, columnLake, columnLowerEstimate, columnHigherEstimate, columnAgreedEstimate, columnAlgorithmCount));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    reportDatabase.close();
    return tempReports;
}

/**
 * This method connects to the database  
 * 
 */

public void CSVReportSelect(){

}

public void delete(){
    this.database.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {        
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
}


private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, time INTEGER, lake TEXT, lower_estimate INTEGER, higher_estimate INTEGER, agreed_estimate INTEGER, algorithm_count INTEGER, xaxis REAL, yaxis REAL, zaxis REAL, altitude REAL, accuracy REAL, photo_identifier TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

}

With the error stack being...

```
ReportDatabase.<init>(Context) line: 29 
ReportDatabase.open(Context) line: 37   
ReviewTab.onCreate(Bundle) line: 26 
Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1123   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord) line: 2231  
ActivityThread.startActivityNow(Activity, String, Intent, ActivityInfo, IBinder, Bundle, Object) line: 2112 
LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord, int) line: 130   
LocalActivityManager.startActivity(String, Intent) line: 342    
TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView() line: 600    
TabHost.setCurrentTab(int) line: 310    
TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(int, boolean) line: 126 
TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(View) line: 268  
RelativeLayout(View).performClick() line: 2183  
RelativeLayout(View).onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 3849   
RelativeLayout(View).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 3389 
RelativeLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 831 
TabWidget(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 863  
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 863   
TabHost(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 863    
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 863    
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 863   
PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 863  
PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 1707   
PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 1197 
HelloFlamingos(Activity).dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 1993 
PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) line: 1691    
ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1525  
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3948    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 782  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 540 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Ideas?

Comment: can we see a stack trace? Android can be tricky to debug and seeing the errors verbatim can help. Also, is that the full ReportDatabase class?

Comment: Could the problem be that I am not closing the database?

Comment: Possibly, have you tried closing the database when you finish using it? What's on lines 29 and 37?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to open the database several times. Use a single ReportDatabase object, available via a static method ReportDatabase. Something like this:

```
class ReportDatabase
{
    static ReportDatabase TheDatabase = null;

    static ReportDatabase Open(Context c)
    {
        if(TheDatabase == null)
            TheDatabase = new ReportDatabase(c);
        return TheDatabase;
    }
}
```

This is often called a singleton. Or a global :)

Comment: I have tried this, and it fails to work, do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're using ReportDatabase.open() throughout the app? Consider making the constructor private to check. If there are constructor calls out there, they will become compile errors.